# How to combine ascending and descending sorting?

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, unix, awk

I have a very big file (many gigabytes) which looks like

**input.txt**

```
a|textA|2
c|textB|4
b|textC|5
e|textD|1
d|textE|4
b|textF|5
```

At the first step, I want to sort lines numerically by the third column in descending order, and if lines have the same value of the third column, they must be sorted by the text of the first column – in ascending order. And if lines have equal values for their 1st and 3rd columns, they must be sorted by the 2nd column in ascending order. The second columns are guaranteed to be unique and different.

So, I want the result to be:

**desiredOutput.txt**

```
b|textC|5
b|textF|5
c|textB|4
d|textE|4
a|textA|2
e|textD|1
```

I can take the first step:

```
sort -t\| -bfrnk3 path/to/input.txt > path/to/output.txt
```

But what is the next steps? And maybe the result might be achieved in a single pass?

**EDIT**
I tested `sort -t '|' -k 3,3nr -k 1,1 -k 2,2 input.txt > output.txt`. It gives the following "output.txt":

```
b|textF|5
b|textC|5
c|textB|4
d|textE|4
a|textA|2
e|textD|1
```

which is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat file
a|textA|2
c|textB|4
b|textC|5
e|textD|1
d|textE|4
b|textF|5
$ sort -t '|' -k 3,3nr -k 1,1 -k 2,2 file
b|textC|5
b|textF|5
c|textB|4
d|textE|4
a|textA|2
e|textD|1
$ sort -t '|' -k 3,3nr file
b|textC|5
b|textF|5
c|textB|4
d|textE|4
a|textA|2
e|textD|1
$
```

`n` in `3,3nr` means *numeric* sorting, `r` means *reverse*. Seems like `-k 1,1 -k 2,2` is optional as I guess `sort` would sort in the *ascending* order by default.

Comment: I don't understand. I took two steps: 1. `sort -t '|' -k 3,3nr -k 1,1 -k 2,2 path/to/input.txt > path/to/pass1output.txt` 2. `sort -t '|' -k 3,3nr path/to/pass1output.txt > path/to/output.txt` The output differs from what I want.

Comment: It gives the output that differs from what I want. Did you check "**desiredOutput.txt**"? Compare it with the resulting file of your answer.

Comment: After the first step (see comment above) - `b|textF|5, b|textC|5, c|textB|4, d|textE|4, a|textA|2, e|textD|1`. After that, the second step does not gives the desired output. And why did you duplicate `sort -t '|' -k 3,3nr`?

Comment: I was not duplicating `-k 3,3nr`. (I did not modify the file `file`.) I was demo'ing that on my system, `-k 3,3nr` is the same as `-k 3,3nr -k 1,1 -k2,2`.

Comment: Not sure why it does not work for you. I'm using GNU `sort`. What OS are you using?

Comment: I use portable version of Cygwin in Windows. It's a bit outdated, but I have never seen any problem with it before.

Comment: Just tested in my cygwin (`CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW 1.7.35(0.287/5/3) 2015-03-04 i686`) and it worked fine too. Did you tried `export LC_ALL=C`?

Comment: No. I never used ths command before and I don't know how is this supposed to be used. Where should I put this command? I tested `export LC_ALL=C | sort -t '|' -k 3,3nr -k 1,1 -k 2,2 inputfile > outputfile`, and the result is the same.

Comment: Just input `LC_ALL=C sort -t '|' -k 3,3nr -k 1,1 -k 2,2 inputfile` and press ENTER. Or run `export LC_ALL=C` as a separate command and then run the `sort` command.

Comment: The result is the same. Actually, I did not expect LC_ALL=C to help. But what an annoying, strange bug! Somewhere the sorting is correct, somewhere not. I did not test it with big files. If the code cannot handle super-simple test file, then in any case, something's wrong...

Comment: Oh, I've found something! Everything is okay **when I put some amount of empty lines in the beginning of the input file**! I wonder what is the source of this bug... And by the way, it seems like a modified and simplified version of that code - `sort -t '|' -k3nr -k1 -k2 input > output` - works fine... Is this version equivalent to `sort -t '|' -k 3,3nr -k 1,1 -k 2,2 input > output`?

Comment: `-k 1 -k 2` is not the same as `-k 1,1 -k 2,2`. For `-k POS1[,POS2]`, the `POS2` defaults to the line's end. For your sample file, replace the line `b|textF|5` with `ba|textF|5` and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If this is UNIX:

```
sort -k 3 path/to/input.txt > path/to/output.txt
```

You can use multiple -k flags to sort on more than one column. For example, to sort by 3rd column then 1st column as a tie breaker:

```
sort -k 3,2 -k 1,1 input.txt > output.txt
```

Relevant options from "man sort":

-k, --key=POS1[,POS2]

start a key at POS1, end it at POS2 (origin 1)

POS is F[.C][OPTS], where F is the field number and C the character position in the field. OPTS is one or more single-letter ordering options, which override global ordering options for that key. If no key is given, use the entire line as the key.

-t, --field-separator=SEP

use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by Sort Command only :-

```
sort -t"|" -k3 -n -k1 -k2 inputFile.txt
```

`k3` specifying that sort according to 3rd column and similarly `k1` & `k2` according to column 1st & 2nd respectively.

Comment: But how to combine descending sorting (numerically) for column 3 and ascending sorting (alphabetically) for columns 1 and 2?