# sort alphanumerically with priority for numbers in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, sh

I want to sort a file alphanumerically but with priority for the numbers in each file entry. Example: File is:

```
22 FAN
14 FTR
16 HHK
19 KOT
25 LMC
22 LOW
22 MOK
22 RAC
22 SHS
18 SHT
20 TAP
19 TAW
23 TWO
15 UNI
```

I want to sort it as:

```
25 LMC
23 TWO
22 FAN
22 LOW
22 MOK
22 RAC
22 SHS
20 TAP
19 KOT
19 TAW
18 SHT
16 HHK
15 UNI
14 FTR
```

Comment: @MadisonCourto I disagree.  He's asking for a way to sort in reverse order for one field, and in natural (ascending) order for the second one, in case the first keys are the same.  See my posted answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine ascending and descending sorting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31508836/608639), [Sorting multiple keys with Unix sort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/357560/608639), [Sorting according to field's numerical value in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4856030/608639), etc.

Comment: @mjuarez sorry, what do you disagree with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically, you're asking to sort the first field numerically in descending order, but if the numeric keys are the same, you want the second field to be ordered in *natural*, or ascending, order.

I tried a few things, but here's the way I managed to make it work:

```
   sort -nk2 file.txt  | sort -snrk1
```

Explanation:

- The first command sorts the whole file using the second, alphanumeric field in natural order, while the second command sorts the output using the first numeric field, shows it in reverse order, and requests that it be a  "stable" sort.
- `-n` is for numeric sort, versus alphanumeric, in which 6 would come before 60.
- `-r` is for reversed order, so from highest to lowest.  If unspecified, it will assume natural, or ascending, order.
- `-k` which **key**, or field, to use for sorting order.
- `-s` for **stable** ordering.  This option maintains the original record order of records that have an equal key.

Comment: `cat file` is unnecessary here, pass the file directly to `sort`

Comment: This sorts the file as                                         
    `25 LMC
    23 TWO
    22 SHS
    22 RAC
    22 MOK
    22 LOW
    22 FAN
    20 TAP
    19 TAW
    19 KOT
    18 SHT
    16 HHK
    15 UNI
    14 FTR`    The numbers are in descending order but so are the words. I need the words with the same number to be sorted alphabetically

Comment: The new code works, thanks!

Comment: @AbhinandanVellanki can you go ahead and accept my answer then?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a *pipe*, or the additional subshell it spawns. Simply use of `keydef` for both fields `1` and `2` will do:

```
$ sort -k1nr,2 file
```

**Example/Output**

```
$ sort -k1nr,2 file
25 LMC
23 TWO
22 FAN
22 LOW
22 MOK
22 RAC
22 SHS
20 TAP
19 KOT
19 TAW
18 SHT
16 HHK
15 UNI
14 FTR
```